# See potential conflicts in git on current file by looking at other branches/PRs?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Where I work, there are several different teams all working on the same code base and merge conflicts are frequent.  Also, it happens that more than one person may be making improvements to the same chunk of code and not be aware of the other person's work until it comes to merge it.

Is there any sort of tool or methodology for dealing with this situation?

I'm using VSCode and was thinking it'd be really helpful if there was a plugin to highlight code that was changed in a pending pull request or an unmerged branch with recent commits.  Or perhaps a bot in github that would comment on your PR about another PR that conflicts with yours.

**EDIT:**

While I'm open to suggestions, I'm specifically looking for solutions to preemptively avoid conflicts before any code has even been written.  After all the code is written then obviously you use the mechanisms of "merge" and rewrite code as needed.  If I could see that the code block I was about to change had a pending PR prior to working on it, then I could potentially coordinate with that person.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I think this is a great idea. Unfortunately Torek just side-tracked the idea you had.

Comment: @hg. No, unfortunately not.  What I end up doing is trying to keep tabs on what other people are doing and try to identify if they are working on anything that may be related to what I'm doing.

Comment: Maybe this link could help. (I haven't tried it yet) The idea is to search in all branch if there is any new modification on a given file.s. But I think it may be too tedious to be useful... Also it may not be much usefull when files has +2000 lines. Maybe there is a way given a line number, of targeting "close changes". 
https://superuser.com/questions/540836/git-find-last-file-modification-on-all-branches

Comment: @Julio.G that looks promising as long as you're working with smaller files.  It's worth knowing those methods of searching in logs exist!

Answer (score 0):

The way to find merge conflicts is ... to merge.

Seriously, just run a test merge.  Do it on *no* branch—on a detached HEAD—if you really want to, but just do it.

The reason for this is simple: merge conflicts occur when both "you" and "they" have:

- touched the same *files*, and

  - within those files, touched *lines* that overlap or abut, or
  - or otherwise cause Git to invoke the `.gitattributes`-directed *merge driver* and it fails.

To find out whether you and they have modified some file(s), you must find the *merge base*.  Finding the merge base is a large part of what `git merge` does—perhaps about 1/5th (20%) of its job.

Then, having found the merge base, to find out whether you and they have touched *the same* files, you must *identify* (match up) files in the merge base with "the same" files—whatever this means to you and/or to Git—in each of the two commits you're merging.  Doing this matching-up is a large part of what `git merge` does.  It might be about 20% of its job.

Now that you have the merge base files identified with their tip-commit counterparts, you must *compare* each such file along with any "high level" operations (add a file, modify a file, rename a file, delete a file).  If there are high level operations that conflict—for instance, if you modified a file and they deleted the same file—then you have found a conflict, which you can note.  This might be about 20% of the job that `git merge` does.

Otherwise, you now have lists of files that you and they modified.  For each such file, if you *both* touched it, it's time to test the low-level merge on that file:

- If there is a merge driver, run it.  If the merge driver fails, you have a conflict on that file.
- Otherwise, compare the modified line ranges.  If they don't overlap or abut (touch at the edges), great!  The changes can be combined successfully.  If not, you have a merge conflict on that file.

This, too, is perhaps about 20% of the job of `git merge` ... or maybe a little more: call it 30%.

Finally, if the merge *succeeds*, `git merge` runs `git commit` on it.  This is the only part of the job you *don't* have to perform.  That's about 10% of the job of `git merge`.

The only part you aren't doing here is the last 10%.  So you're going to repeat 90% of what `git merge` does, just to find out if there is a merge conflict.  You might as well just run `git merge`.  If you like, you can run `git merge --no-commit` to make `git merge` *skip* that last 10% when it succeeds: you're going to reset the merge away, or abandon it, either way.  But to find out *whether* there is a conflict, you have to do almost everything `git merge` would do, so why not just run `git merge`?

**Important note:** `git merge`, with or without `--no-commit`, exits zero on success (merge completed) and nonzero on failure, so you don't have to examine the index for conflicts, and I think that in fact you can't *find* some high-level conflicts—such as rename/delete—*ex post facto* in the index if they're complex enough.  So just run `git merge --no-commit`, save its status and any error messages about conflicts, and then `git merge --abort` if needed to abandon the result.  You will need a clean index and work-tree; consider providing them via `git worktree add`, if you want to be especially fancy.  You can set up the added worktree with a detached HEAD, run the merge operation, then remove the added worktree (and run `git worktree prune` to clean up after yourself) instead of using `git merge --abort`.

Comment: I think the issue is more seeing the possible issues before starting to work on code.  So, for example, seeing that someone else made changes to a class you're about to work on and that they've added methods you were going to implement or could use.

Comment: @TimTisdall: either way, the answer is still "run a test merge": it's about 4 commands (create worktree, run test merge, remove worktree, purge worktree) if your Git is at least version 2.5. Or, if you just want to eyeball things: `git diff HEAD...origin/somebranch` will show you the comparison of a merge base of your `HEAD` commit with your `origin/somebranch` commit. That doesn't show you what *you* changed; for that, run another diff: `git diff origin/somebranch...HEAD`. Note: **three** dots.

Comment: maybe I'm not being clear.  I'm talking about the situation where I am just creating a new branch with no content in and and nothing to merge.  I'm about to work on a section of code and would like to know prior to making any changes whether anyone else has made changes on this chunk of code prior to me starting.  Also, I don't know which branches also affect that chunk of code and I'd have to test merge with every other branch to see if there was a conflict.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "branch with no content". Branches contain *commits* and commits are snapshots. To create a new branch, you pick some existing commit and say "this is the end of this new branch". It now has all commits leading up to that final commit. As you make *new* commits, it accumulates additional commits. Each one has a snapshot—whatever you have in Git's index (aka staging area) at the time you make the commit. So pick an existing commit, create a branch, and your branch ends at that commit.

Comment: If you're used to other version control systems, this is *weird*. Git's branches don't work like other version control systems' branches.

Comment: If I do `git checkout -b my_new_branch`, is that not a branch with no content?

Comment: It is not a branch with no content. It is a branch whose *tip* commit is the same commit you were on a moment ago. If you were on some other branch, both branches now mean *the same commit*, and both contain *all* the same commits.

Comment: @torek I think the main thing for @Tim to understand is that branches are just pointers to revisions.... you can create them, delete them, move them around... stack them (as in create 10 branches all pointing to the same revisions). So, when you run `git checkout -b my_new_branch` you are checking out a new branch that is pointing to whatever revision you were when you ran the command from.... so if you were on a branch that had 200 revisions, well, your new branch has those same 200 revisions.

Comment: And no point in preemptively knowing what's going on.... you checkout from whatever point you need to start from and when you are done you can try rebasing with whatever is on the branch you are targeting... if it were possible to know before hand what people are working on on feature branches, is it guaranteed that those changes will make it into the target branch? No, right? Then what is the point? Just code and rebase when you are done before you push your branch and ask the code to be merged.

Comment: @eftshift0 - the point is, I could talk to those people and coordinate.  I'm asking if there's a tool to help see these changes without having to inspect every branch manually or make my changes and then afterwards go "I wish I knew they were working on this earlier".

Comment: Imagine you had some other VCS where branches actually mean something (they don't in Git). But imagine it's a *distributed* VCS, as Git is. Group X goes off and implements a feature that you could use, but *they never tell you they're doing this, and never give you their branch.* What can you do about that? Now imagine they *do* tell you. How do they tell you? What information do they give you?

Comment: @torek - I'm asking if there's a tool to see changes already committed (and sent to Github) to a particular file across all (or select) branches (existing on Github).  If I could see those changes, knew who made them, and knew whether they were eventually going to be merged with code I intended to write, I could coordinate.

Comment: Again, commits hold *snapshots*. Consider these temperature snapshots: if it's 20 degrees C outside today and 20 degrees a week ago, how different is today from yesterday? What is missing from this picture, in order to answer that question?

Comment: You need to choose which *commits* to compare. You can see all commits that are on GitHub, or more easily, use `git fetch` to bring them to your own repository, but then *you* must decide which commits to compare. Use your remote-tracking names (`origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on) to find commits. Pick some other older commit to compare them to, and you'll see what changed between the older commit and each of those newer commits.

Comment: The primary tool that compares two commits—or one file in two commits—is `git diff`. You give it two commit hash IDs, and it tells you what, if anything, is different. That's really all there is to it: pick two commits, run `git diff a123456 b789abc` or `git diff a123456 b789abc -- myfile.ext` or whatever, and you see the difference.